# Container is running beyond physical memory and killed on request (code 143)

Tags: query-performance, query, memory, aws, hiveql

I ran a query which involved a `JOIN` and an `AVG` operation:

```
SELECT
  AVG(user_amount) AS average_user_per_game 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      start_time
     ,end_time
     ,COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS user_amount 
   FROM 
     (
       SELECT 
         start_time
        ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(start_time) + 3600 * 4) AS end_time 
       FROM 
         table1 
       WHERE
         <conditions>
     ) a
   JOIN
     (
       SELECT 
         session_start_date_time
        ,ID 
       FROM 
         table2 
       WHERE 
         app_id = 'SOMETHING'
     ) b
       ON b.session_start_date_time >= a.start_time
           AND b.session_start_date_time <= a.end_time
    GROUP BY
      start_time
     ,end_time
) users
```

Which returned the following:

```
Status: Failed
Application application_XXXXXXX failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_XXXXXXX exited with  exitCode: -104
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2021-08-17 17:41:17.384]Container [pid=XXXX,containerID=container_XXXX] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.0 GB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.8 GB of 5 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
[2021-08-17 17:41:17.397]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2021-08-17 17:41:17.407]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: SOME URL Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
```

What should I modify to let it run without errors?

Comment: Hi, welcome to DBA.SE - please update your question with table definitions and read this to help others with the information they need: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example